# Constructing a dictionary of ID, and keyvalue pair

Tags: c#

I'm a c# beginner developer
I would like to model 
Unique Level ID --> Keyvalue [ String, int]

so I made

```
// Level ID -->[String][Progress] 
private Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<string, int>> LevelProgress;
```

and I would like when I add a level progress, I only want to have the ability to add to current progress, and if there is no progress, add a new one. The problem is I can't add to "current" keyvalue pair any new integer.

```
   public int AddProgress(int levelID, KeyValuePair<string, int> pair)
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, int> storedValue;
        if (LevelProgress.TryGetValue(levelID, out storedValue))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            // add progress
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Show us how you're trying to "add progress". Are you not already passing it the `pair`? In the else you're adding progress, if you're adding this to an entry that already exists in the dictionary you've got problems as it would've satisfied the `if` if it exists.

Comment: I couldn't assign the new keyvalue pair to the storedvalue. ( a compiler error)

Comment: A `KeyValuePair<Tk, Tv>` is a struct, you can't modify it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter so change it to a dictionary? what would the best design ?

Comment: You can't do `LevelProgress.Add(123, new KeyValuePair<string, int>("blah", 456));`?

Comment: Why don't you use `private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>> LevelProgress;`

Comment: @Mahmoud: yes, you could use a `Dictionary`, but you are you trying to do actually? Maybe you need a custom class instead.

Comment: DavidG, I can but why add a new String to the keyvaluepair, I want to keep it.

Comment: So you don't need a KVP, you need a List/Dictionary/something else.

Comment: but why should I pass a whole dictionary to the function? can't I add just a keyvalue pair ?

Comment: @T00rk, so to addProgress, I need to pass a dictionary as a parameter ?

Comment: Another Question I forgot. What do you put in your LevelProgress ? Is it a single <string, int> or an array of <string, int> ?

Comment: @T00rk single <string, int>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear to me from your question what you're trying to achieve. Here are some tests that I think describe what you're attempting...

```
[TestFixture]
    class GameTests
    {

        [Test]
        public void AddKeyValuePair()
        {
            var levelProgress = new Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
            KeyValuePair<string, int> storedValue;
            if (levelProgress.TryGetValue(1, out storedValue))
            {
                Assert.Fail("shouldn't get here");
            }
            else
            {
                levelProgress[1] = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("something", 1);
            }

            Assert.IsTrue(levelProgress.ContainsKey(1));
            Assert.IsTrue(levelProgress[1].Equals(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("something", 1)));
        }

        [Test]
        public void UpdateKeyValuePair()
        {
            var levelProgress = new Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<string, int>>
            {
                {1, new KeyValuePair<string, int>("something", 1)}
            };
            KeyValuePair<string, int> storedValue;
            if (levelProgress.TryGetValue(1, out storedValue))
            {
                //any operation
                levelProgress[1] = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("newness", 100);
            }
            else
            {
                Assert.Fail("shouldn't get here");
            }

            Assert.IsTrue(levelProgress.ContainsKey(1));
            Assert.IsTrue(levelProgress[1].Equals(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("something", 2)));
        }
    }
```

However, it really feels (and Tuples/KeyValuePairs often suggest this to me) that you're missing some classes that clarify your intent.

e.g. and this is a guess...

```
class Game
{
  private Dictionary<int, LevelProgress> levelsProgress;

  LevelProgress GetLevel(int i);
}

class LevelProgress
{
  void AddProgress;
}
```

Comment: but I don't want to increment a new storedValue.value, I want to store the new stored.value

Comment: ok, I've updated the code so that it replaces the KeyValuePair.

Comment: is it ok say:
levelProgress[1] = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(stored.key, stored.value);

Comment: yep, you can carry out any valid operation there... it all depends on what the software is trying to do which is why it's probably better to encapsulate your knowledge in some classes which expose the operations...

Comment: is it ok if I want to return a null keyvaluepair to do that
return default(KeyValuePair<string, int>);
If I couldn't find it in the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Define a `Progress`class with 2 properties

```
public class Progress
{
    private string sLabel = null;
    public string Label
    {
        get { return this.sLabel; }
        set { this.sLabel = value; }
    }

    private int iValue = -1;
    public int Value 
    {
        get { return this.iValue ; }
        set { this.iValue = value; }
    }

    public Progress()
    {

    }

    public Progress(string Label, int Value)
    {
        this.sLabel = Label;
        this.iValue = Value;
    }
}
```

Your LevelProgress is now a Dictionary containing int Key and Progress value

```
private Dictionary<int, Progress> LevelProgress;
```

Add progress Like this

```
public int AddProgress(int levelID, Progress P)
{
    if(LevelProgress.ContainsKey(levelID))
    {
        LevelProgress[levelID] = P;
    }
    else
    {
        LevelProgress.Add(levelID, P);
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to get a unique Key in the progress class?

Comment: ok in that class Progress, the label is variable, I don't want to store duplicated labels..only unique

Comment: But you'll only have one Progress object by level so nothing will be duplicated

Comment: yes I will have one progress per object, but Progress's label can be duplicated, and I don't want that.